# Add new key value pair in a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am really stuck with a problem here, I am new to python and using it for a typical requirement. I want to add key value pairs into a dictionary within a loop for eg:

```
Eg_dict={}
for row in iterable:
    dict={row[1],row[2]}
```

This code doesn't do what I want to achieve, this just adds the very last record of the iterable into the dictionary, its easy to assume that my code is reading each record from iterable and rewriting the dictionary over and over again.

So my question is simple how to add all the records from the iterable in the dictionary? This would be the default behavior of an array in unix.

P.S: the iterable here can be assumed as a csv.reader object and I am trying to insert the second and third columns into the dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use dictionary assignment:

```
for row in iterable:
    Eg_dict[row[1]] = row[2]
```

or ever replace the whole code with a dict comprehension:

```
Eg_dict = {row[1]: row[2] for row in iterable}  # python 2.7 and up
```

or

```
Eg_dict = dict(row[1:3] for row in iterable)    # python 2.3 and up
```

If each `row` has a fixed number of entries, you can use tuple assignment:

```
for key, value in row:  # two elements
```

or

```
for _, key, value in row:  # three elements, ignore the first
```

to make a loop more readable. E.g. `{key: value for _, key, value in iterable}`.

Your code instead creates a new **set** object (just unique values, no keys) each loop, replacing the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nice list comprehension for this:

```
d = dict([(row[1], row[2]) for row in iterable])
```

This will work in any Python version.

If you use 2.7+ or 3, you can use the cleaner dict comprehension:

```
d = {row[1]:row[2] for row in iterable}
```